# Theme div.item-list of views pager?

Tags: theming

How can I theme the div with a class of item-list that appears around a views pager? All I need to do is add an additional class to this div when it surrounds a pager.

I can find lots of documentation on theming the content of the pager, but none on how to theme them this div.

Comment: What you could do is create a custom ```views-view--myview-someblock.tpl.php``` override in your theme and then wrap a div with a custom class around ```<?php print $pager; ?>```.  This is not exactly what you asked for but it would give you specificity in styling this pager so in the long run it might work for you.

Comment: I was hoping for a 'global' solution but yes I may need to do it this way.

Comment: If it's global, then why do you need the specificity of this specific pager? Maybe I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I meant global for all pagers. I want to be able to add markup to all views pagers in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, unless you are using a specific contributed module, the pager is a template file that comes with views. You can override `theme_pager` for the specific view (or all your paged views) and add the additional div.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7

Examples on how to do this:
https://www.drupal.org/node/387786

Comment: Which file is this? Ive looked in the theme folder in the views module and I cant see it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was incorrect. It is actually a theme function called `theme_pager` (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) and this page might be able to help you: https://www.drupal.org/node/387786

Answer (score 0):

function theme_pager https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7

Its only the very end of the file where anything needs to be changed, by the code comment "Add a div"

```
function THEMENAME_theme_pager($variables) {
  $tags = $variables['tags'];
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $parameters = $variables['parameters'];
  $quantity = $variables['quantity'];
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;

  // Calculate various markers within this pager piece:
  // Middle is used to "center" pages around the current page.
  $pager_middle = ceil($quantity / 2);
  // current is the page we are currently paged to
  $pager_current = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
  // first is the first page listed by this pager piece (re quantity)
  $pager_first = $pager_current - $pager_middle + 1;
  // last is the last page listed by this pager piece (re quantity)
  $pager_last = $pager_current + $quantity - $pager_middle;
  // max is the maximum page number
  $pager_max = $pager_total[$element];
  // End of marker calculations.
  // Prepare for generation loop.
  $i = $pager_first;
  if ($pager_last > $pager_max) {
    // Adjust "center" if at end of query.
    $i = $i + ($pager_max - $pager_last);
    $pager_last = $pager_max;
  }
  if ($i <= 0) {
    // Adjust "center" if at start of query.
    $pager_last = $pager_last + (1 - $i);
    $i = 1;
  }
  // End of generation loop preparation.

  $li_first = theme('pager_first', array('text' => (isset($tags[0]) ? $tags[0] : t('« first')), 'element' => $element, 'parameters' => $parameters));
  $li_previous = theme('pager_previous', array('text' => (isset($tags[1]) ? $tags[1] : t('‹ previous')), 'element' => $element, 'interval' => 1, 'parameters' => $parameters));
  $li_next = theme('pager_next', array('text' => (isset($tags[3]) ? $tags[3] : t('next ›')), 'element' => $element, 'interval' => 1, 'parameters' => $parameters));
  $li_last = theme('pager_last', array('text' => (isset($tags[4]) ? $tags[4] : t('last »')), 'element' => $element, 'parameters' => $parameters));

  if ($pager_total[$element] > 1) {
    if ($li_first) {
      $items[] = array(
          'class' => array('pager-first'),
          'data' => $li_first,
      );
    }
    if ($li_previous) {
      $items[] = array(
          'class' => array('pager-previous'),
          'data' => $li_previous,
      );
    }

    // When there is more than one page, create the pager list.
    if ($i != $pager_max) {
      if ($i > 1) {
        $items[] = array(
            'class' => array('pager-ellipsis'),
            'data' => '…',
        );
      }
      // Now generate the actual pager piece.
      for (; $i <= $pager_last && $i <= $pager_max; $i++) {
        if ($i < $pager_current) {
          $items[] = array(
              'class' => array('pager-item'),
              'data' => theme('pager_previous', array('text' => $i, 'element' => $element, 'interval' => ($pager_current - $i), 'parameters' => $parameters)),
          );
        }
        if ($i == $pager_current) {
          $items[] = array(
              'class' => array('pager-current'),
              'data' => $i,
          );
        }
        if ($i > $pager_current) {
          $items[] = array(
              'class' => array('pager-item'),
              'data' => theme('pager_next', array('text' => $i, 'element' => $element, 'interval' => ($i - $pager_current), 'parameters' => $parameters)),
          );
        }
      }
      if ($i < $pager_max) {
        $items[] = array(
            'class' => array('pager-ellipsis'),
            'data' => '…',
        );
      }
    }
    // End generation.
    if ($li_next) {
      $items[] = array(
          'class' => array('pager-next'),
          'data' => $li_next,
      );
    }
    if ($li_last) {
      $items[] = array(
          'class' => array('pager-last'),
          'data' => $li_last,
      );
    }
    // Add a div 
    return '<div class="pager-wrap"><h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('Pages') . '</h2>' . theme('item_list', array(
                'items' => $items,
                'attributes' => array('class' => array('pager'))
            )) . '</div>';
  }
}
```